# Simple algorithm for generating random numbers with bigger/smaller probability

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

I'm currently working on a game, with scrollable screen and I need to find a simple algorithm for placing obstacles in the game. I have a `gameSpeed`, that is increased in time (from 1 to 12, increased by 0.005 each 1/60s) and a range of available positions between 200 and 600 (ints). I'd like to achieve a bigger probability of receiving smaller number when the speed is bigger, but it's my 14th hour straight coding and I cannot come up with anything usable and not overcomplicated. I'd like to minimize Math and random functions so that the rendering loop won't take too long. Any help appreciated !

Comment: Generating random numbers and doing a bit maths will hardly slow down your game noticeable.

Comment: I think that you can use nth root of random number, but you have to calibrate factor and it is a little slow: `Math.pow(Math.random() * something, -gameSpeed) + 200` and i think that `something = Math.pow(400,gameSpeed) Also you can use other curve eg. logarithmic, but still it's not as fast as it should be...

Answer (score 5):

You could square or square-root the random number to shift the density in one direction. `Math.random()*Math.random()` will have a higher probability to produce smaller numbers (near 0) than higher ones (near 1).

Your formula could be like

```
var position = Math.pow(Math.random(), gameSpeed / 3) * 400 + 200;
```

Comment: For `var position = Math.pow(Math.random(), gameSpeed / 2 - 3) * 400 + 200` when gameSpeed = 6, position always equals 600.

Comment: works fine with speed '12', but with 1, I'm getting numbers as high as for example 16470

Comment: Ooops, you're right. The exponent may never become negative or zero. For `< 1` it will generate bigger numbers, for `1` it will generate a uniform distribution, and for `> 1` it generates more smaller numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer I can think of is to create an array having more lower numbers compared to higher ones, for example, for producing random between [1,5] (both inclusive). So your array may look like `[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]`

And when you randomly pick an element from that array you will have a higher chance of picking up low number compared to high one.

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to have two (or more) percentages:

say, start with 10% of the time we access 90% of the range, and 90% of the time we access the other 10%. Then we gradually flip those numbers as the speed increases. For example,

```
var lBound = 200,
    uBound = 600,
    range = uBound - lBound,
    gameSpeed = 1,
    initialMarker = 0.1,
    percentageRange = 1 - 2 * initialMarker,
    marker = (gameSpeed - 1) / 11 * percentageRange + initialMarker,
    position

Math.random() <= marker ? position = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - marker) * range) + lBound 
                        : position = uBound - Math.floor(Math.random() * marker * range)

console.log(position)
```

Try changing `gameSpeed` and see what happens. Change `initialMarker` for a different set of percentages (currently set at 0.1, which means 10% / 90%).